# How can I build a ThreadId given that I know the actual number?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

It often happens to me when debugging or playing around in GHCi that I happen to know the actual `ThreadId` number (for example from using `Debug.Trace`), but that's all I have.

The problem is that all thread APIs, such as `killThread` require a `ThreadId` and not an `Int`.

I've tried Hoogle but came out empty. Is there a way to do this? I'm concerned mostly with debugging, so I don't mind if it's a nasty hack or if it's through a GHC-only library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't. `ThreadId` is abstract. The `Int` you have is actually nothing more than a counter ([source](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/rts/Threads.c)):

```
32  static StgThreadID next_thread_id = 1;
...
59  StgTSO *
60  createThread(Capability *cap, W_ size)
61  {
62      StgTSO *tso;
...
126     ACQUIRE_LOCK(&sched_mutex);
127     tso->id = next_thread_id++;  // while we have the mutex
...
130     RELEASE_LOCK(&sched_mutex);
...
136 }
...
161 int
162 rts_getThreadId(StgPtr tso) 
163 {
164   return ((StgTSO *)tso)->id;
165 }
```

It's `rts_getThreadId` that gets called in `ThreadId`'s `Show` instance. There's no mapping back to the actual TSO. If you want to know what `ThreadId` belongs to what `Int`, you need to keep track of them yourself. You could, for example, parse the `Int` and fill a `Map`.

Comment: I can't believe I actually went down the rabbit hole and had a look at the GHC sources. Madness is slowly but surely taking over.