# How can I manually kill a thread?

Tags: haskell

I'm in `ghci` testing some functions that fork threads, kinda like this:

```
myForkingFunction = do
  tid <- forkIO (workerFunction)
  putStrLn ("Worker thread: " ++ show tid)
  putStrLn ("...lots of other actions...")

  where workerFunction = do 
          putStrLn "In real life I'm listening for jobs...."
          workerFunction
```

This results in:

```
  > myForkingFunction
Worker thread: ThreadId 216
...lots of other actions...
  > In real life I'm listening for jobs....
In real life I'm listening for jobs....
In real life I'm listening for jobs....
In real life I'm listening for jobs....
```

(and so on)

Then as I'm `:r`-ing and iterating on the code, I notice that even when I reload, my `workerFunction` is still going.

So, I thought could just look at the printed output and do `killThread (ThreadId 234)` or whatever.

But first, I need to import `ThreadId(..)` from `GHC.Conc.Sync`?

Then I get this error:

```
<interactive>:110:22: error:
    • Couldn't match a lifted type with an unlifted type
      When matching types
        Integer :: *
        GHC.Prim.ThreadId# :: TYPE 'GHC.Types.UnliftedRep
    • In the first argument of ‘ThreadId’, namely ‘805’
      In the first argument of ‘killThread’, namely ‘(ThreadId 805)’
      In the expression: killThread (ThreadId 805)
```

So I think I must be approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to construct a `ThreadId` (e.g. from the result of `show`). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995262/how-can-i-build-a-threadid-given-that-i-know-the-actual-number) so you'll need to hold on to the `ThreadId` returned from `forkIO`, e.g. by changing your function to:

```
myForkingFunction = do
  tid <- forkIO (workerFunction)
  putStrLn ("Worker thread: " ++ show tid)
  putStrLn ("...lots of other actions...")
  return tid
```

and doing in ghci:

```
> tid <- myForkingFunction
> killThread tid
```

The error you get is a little confusing, and I believe has to do with the fact that numeric literals (like `216`) are polymorphic; the argument to `ThreadId` is `ThreadId#` which is an unlifted type so you get the error you see before the compiler can even complain of "no instance Num ThreadId#"

Answer (score 5):

`ThreadId` values are treated specially by the runtime. You can't just create one. You need access to a `ThreadId` either as produced by `forkIO` when creating the thread or by `myThreadId` inside the thread.

Just for extra fun, threads don't get garbage collected while any `ThreadId` from one is still reachable. So you can't just hold on to them in case you need them. You need to actually have a plan to manage threads.

I think you're probably best off using the [async library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) and it's various linking operations to ensure that when the parent thread is killed, it also kills all its child threads. It's a little (or a lot) of an awkward code style, but it's the best way to get correct behavior.

Comment: OTOH, you *can* hang on to a weak pointer to a `ThreadId` using `mkWeakThreadId :: ThreadId -> IO (Weak ThreadId)`, then use `deRefWeak wk >>= maybe (return ()) killThread`. Still not so nice...

Comment: "threads don't get garbage collected while any ThreadId from one is still reachable"
Can you say a little more about this? (or link?)

Comment: @Libby looks like the memory used by the stack created for the new thread is held on to as long as the ThreadId is reachable. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#t:ThreadId

Comment: @Carl Ah, okay, that's what I thought, I was worried you were saying if I create multiple threads, then they won't be garbage collected until ALL the threads are unreachable

Answer (score 3):

A `ThreadId` is not really a number, although it has a number associated with it for identification. `ThreadId` is a wrapper around `ThreadId#`, which is a pointer to a thread state object (a TSO, or in the RTS code, `StgTSO`). That object contains all the actual internal information about a thread. There is no way to turn an `Int` into a `ThreadId` (I'm pretty sure the runtime system doesn't even maintain a mapping from thread ID numbers to `ThreadId#`s, and there's definitely no primop supporting such a conversion), so you can give up on that now. The only way you can `killThread` or `throwTo` a thread is if you hold on to the `ThreadId` that `forkIO` gave you. Note that killing a thread isn't usually the way you want to stop it. Normally you want to do something more controlled by communicating with it through an `MVar`. Most people use the tools in the `async` library to manage concurrency.

Answer (score -6):

The problem is in the arguments of the killThread is wrong. You need to write `killThread 234` instead of `killThread (ThreadId 234)`. Have you tried that?

Comment: `ThreadId` is not an instance of `Num` (and it can't be made one), so `killThread 234` will give a type error.